# How to remove everything before first occurrence of comma in R

Tags: r, regex

I am using trying to remove the text up until the first comma in a string that has one or more commas. For some reason I am finding that this always removes everything up until the last comma for all strings.

The string looks like:

```
OCR - (some text), Variant - (some text), Bad Subtype - (some text)
```

and my regex is returning:

```
Bad Subtype - (some text)
```

when the desired output is:

```
Variant - (some text), Bad Subtype - (some text)
```

Variant is not guaranteed to be in the second position.

```
#select all strings beginning with OCR in the column Tags
clean<- subset(all, grepl("^OCR", all$Tags)
#trim the OCR text up to the first comma, and store in a new column called Tag
    clean$Tag<- gsub(".*,", "", clean$Tag)
```

or

```
clean$Tag <- gsub(".*\\,", "", clean$Tag)
```

or

```
clean$Tag<- sub(".*,", "", clean$Tag)
```

etc..

Comment: The problem you're having is your `*` operator is greedy. See [What do lazy and greedy mean in the context of regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) for more info.

Comment: The dupe tagged is different.  It is about whitespace

Comment: I am also calling str_trim(x, side="both"), once I have finished trimming

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one regex that does the job.

```
x <- "OCR - (some text), Variant - (some text), Bad Subtype - (some text) and my regex is returning: Bad Subtype - (some text) when the desired output is: Variant - (some text), Bad Subtype - (some text)"

sub("^[^,]*,", "", x)
#[1] " Variant - (some text), Bad Subtype - (some text) and my regex is returning: Bad Subtype - (some text) when the desired output is: Variant - (some text), Bad Subtype - (some text)"
```

**Explanation**

1. `^` beginning of string;
2. `^[^,]*` any character at the beginning except for `","` repeated zero or more times;
3. `^[^,]*,` the pattern in point 2 above followed by a comma.

This pattern replaced by the empty string `""`.

Answer (score 5):

An option with `trimws` from `base R`

```
trimws(x, whitespace = "^[^,]+,\\s*")
```

-output

```
#[1] "Variant - (some text), Bad Subtype - (some text) and my regex is returning: Bad Subtype - (some text) when the desired output is: Variant - (some text), Bad Subtype - (some text)"
```

#### data

```
x <- "OCR - (some text), Variant - (some text), Bad Subtype - (some text) and my regex is returning: Bad Subtype - (some text) when the desired output is: Variant - (some text), Bad Subtype - (some text)"
```